# Defining a Proxy used by the Azure IoT Hub Client (Python)

Tags: python, azure, proxy, azure-iot-hub

I am using the Azure IoT Hub Client SDK for Python. I am using a slightly modified  version of the sample script from the github repo to upload files to the IoT Hub. Everything works fine as long as I do not have to use a proxy for outgoing connections.

I tried to understand how to configurate a proxy for this, but I did not find anything for the Python SDK. I searched also in the other SDKs and found some ProxySettings in the [iothub_client_options.h](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/1ad2c5355a3d9759493eda9b41647c34b845ec20/iothub_client/inc/iothub_client_options.h) of the C SDK. But I do not know how to set these settings in the python client (in case the settings are actually working).
I also found an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/45) that the connection over websockets needs some special format of the Linux environment variables. But I do not use websockets.

I tried to run my script both in Windows and Linux environments where the proxy system settings are correctly configured (Win: Internet settings, Linux: environment variables).

Is there any documentation on this topic? Does anybody how to configure a proxy either on windows or on linux?

Comment: I suggest you to write here too: https://github.com/azure/azure-iot-sdk-python to help having an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience, I think you can run the python script using Azure IoTHub Client SDK without any proxy settings to communicate with Azure IoT Hub if the OS configured correctly the proxy.

However, there are some notes which need to be focused by using different protocol (such as `HTTP`, `Socks`, etc) configured in proxy server, as below.

1. Normally, the proxy server was configured for working on `HTTP` protocol which only allow the `HTTP` communication. So if using IoTHub Client within `HTTP` mode, the script will works fine, but not works within `AMQP`/`MQTT` mode.
2. If the proxy server was configured for working on `Socks` protocol, such as `Socks4`/`Socks5`, the script within any mode will works fine, because the `Socks` protocol just transmit datagram, not check the protocol type.

So please check which protocols be supported in your proxy server, then to use `HTTP` mode or configure `Socks` protocol for proxy to make the script works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can verify that it is working now after I also configured the HTTPS proxy (I am using HTTP protocol). Thanks!

Comment: I have now the problem that the authentication (using HTTPS proxy) is not working on a specific proxy server (others are working fine). I assume that the HTTP authentication header is droped by the proxy. Is there any solution to this problem? (this could be an question on its own, but maybe there is a simple solution which I currently miss).